# &array == array, what about structs?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, reference

I just started messing with structs and pointers.

Here's my .h :

```
#ifndef struct_struct_h
#include <string.h>
#define struct_struct_h



#endif


int count=0;

typedef struct
{
    int num;
    double balance;
    const char * name;
    struct Account * acnt;
    
} Account;

Account* a = NULL;

Account* new_account(const char * n)
{
    Account *a1 = malloc(sizeof(Account));
    
    a1->num=++count;
    a1->name = n;
    return a1;
}
```

Here's my main.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "struct.h"



int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    // insert code here...
    Account* accounts[2];
    
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        accounts[i] = (i==0 ? new_account("David") : new_account("Toto") );
    }
    printf("Accounts array address is %i\n",&accounts);
    
    for(int i=0; i<2;i++)
    {
        printf("Account n°%i is owned by %s \n, its address is %i\n",accounts[i]->num,accounts[i]->name,&accounts[i]);
    }
    printf("There are %i accounts.\n",count);
    
    return 0;
}
```

If I replace &accounts by accounts, I get the same result : @array, either is &accounts[0], it's ok.

> Accounts array address is 1606416480

If I do replace &accounts by *accounts, I get this :

> Accounts array address is 1063600

Second output is :

> Account n°1 is owned by David
> , its address is 1606416480
>
> Account n°2 is owned by Toto
> , its address is 1606416488

Actually these are the @ of account pointers contained in accounts, these @ take 8B each selves in memory.

If I replace &accounts[i] by accounts[i], then by *accounts[i] I get :

> Account n°1 is owned by David
> , its address is 1063600
>
> Account n°2 is owned by Toto  , its address is 1063632
>
> Account n°1 is owned by David
> , its address is 3874
>
> Account n°2 is owned by Toto
> , its address is 3880

In the first case I have 2 pointers, and in the second I have 2 *pointers.

*STRUCT and STRUCT are different, why ?

Comment: use `%p` with a cast of the argument to `void *` to print address.

Comment: If an array was a pointer, it would be called "pointer", not "array"! &array is **not** the same as `array`. Even **iff** an array _decays_ most time to a pointer, it is a different pointer. And you have more than this missconception: Your "header" is wrong. Please look around what a header has to contain and what the guard actually is meant for.

Comment: I'm pretty new to C and I've read that "public" structs should be declared in a header.

Comment: Note: Allocation problem: Use `Account *a1 = malloc(sizeof *Account);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array is internally represented as a contiguous extent of memory. In the very beginning of the extent there is placed the first element of the array.

If you have an array named for example the same way as in your question `accounts` then the address of the array and the address of the first element of the array have the same value.

If to consider your example then you have

```
Account * accounts[2];
```

Arrays in expressions with rare exceptions as for example using them in the sizeof operator are converted to pointers to their first elements.

Thus expression `accounts` has type `Account **` and the equation

```
accounts == &accounts[0]
```

evaluates to true.

Expression `&accounts` has the same value because it is the address of the extent but a different type. Its type is

```
Account * ( * )[2]
```

That is if you write for example

```
Account *( *p )[2] = accounts;

printf( "*p = %zu\n", sizeof( *p ) );
```

then the output will be equal to 16 because in the environment where you run your own code the size of pointers is equal to 8 and the array consists from two elements that are pointers.

You may not write condition

```
&accounts == accounts
```

because the operands have different types. But if you write

```
( void *)&accounts == ( void * ) accounts
```

then this condition evaluates to true.

So the values of expressions

`&accounts`, `accounts`, and `&accounts[0]` are equal each other and are the address of the memory extent occupied by the array.

As for structures then the address of a structure is equal to the address of its first member. However names of objects of a structure type are not implicitly converted to pointers to their first members.

> If I replace &accounts[i] by accounts[i], then by *accounts[i] I get :

`&accounts[i]` gives the address of the element of the array. So you will get values

```
Account n°1 is owned by David , its address is 1606416480

Account n°2 is owned by Toto , its address is 1606416488
```

The difference between the values is equal to `8` that is the value of expression `sizeof( Account * )`

`accounts[i]` gives the values stored in the elements of the array. They are addresses of the dynamically alllocated memory for each object of the structure type.

*accounts[i] is an object of the structure type. As the format specifier in the call of printf does not corresponds to the object passed as an argument then the function behaviour is undefined.

Take into account that to print pointers you have to use format specifier `%p`.

Comment: Thank you a lot Vlad for your answer, since I began writing with C I visualize memory as a big array. This approach helps me understand about the correlation between mutability and references in higher-level languages.

Answer (score 0):

**TL/DR version:**

Arrays are special, and under most circumstances an array expression is treated as a pointer to the first element of the array.  `a` and `&a` will yield the same value (address of the first element of the array `a`), although the types of the expressions will be different.

This is not the case with `struct` types (or any other aggregate type).

**David Foster Wallace version:**

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "`N`-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element in the array.

Why is this the case?

First of all, let's look at how an array is represented in memory.  Given the declaration

```
T a[N];
```

then you get something that looks like this:

```
   +---+
a: |   | a[0]
   +---+
   |   | a[1]
   +---+
    ...
   +---+
   |   | a[N-1]
   +---+
```

Storage is set aside for the array elements and *nothing else*; there's no storage for any metadata, or for any pointer to the first element of the array.  Critically, there's no object `arr` apart from the array elements (said another way, the object `arr` *is* the array elements).

But the array subscript operation `a[i]` is *defined* as `*(a + i)`; that is, given an address `a`, we offset `i` elements (*not bytes!*) from that address and dereference the result.

But `a` is an *array*, not a pointer, so how can that work?

Like this - except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize another array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "`N`-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array<sup>1</sup>.

Thus, in code like

```
printf( "a = %p\n", (void *) a ); // *always* use `%p` to print pointer values
```

the expression `a` is not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, so it is converted ("decays") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression is the address of the first element.

Here's a handy table to remember some of this:

```
  Expression        Type        "Decays" to        Value
  ----------        ----        -----------        -----
           a        T [N]       T *                Address of first element 
          &a        T (*)[N]    n/a                Same value as above, different type
          *a        T           n/a                Value of first element
        a[i]        T           n/a                Value of i'th element
       &a[i]        T *         n/a                Address of i'th element
    sizeof a        size_t      n/a                Number of bytes in array
   sizeof *a        size_t      n/a                Number of bytes in single element
 sizeof a[i]        size_t      n/a                Same as above
   sizeof &a        size_t      n/a                Number of bytes in pointer to array
sizeof &a[i]        size_t      n/a                Number of bytes in pointer to single element
```

Thus, `sizeof a == sizeof (T [N])`, `sizeof *a == sizeof (T)`, `sizeof &a == sizeof (T (*)[N])`, and `sizeof &a[i] == sizeof (T *)`.

Notice that the expressions `a`, `&a`, and `&a[0]` all yield the same *value* (the address of the first element of the array), but the *types* of the expressions will be different.  `a` and `*&a[0]` both have type `T *` (pointer to `T`), but `&a` has type `T (*)[N]` (pointer to `N`-element array of `T`).  This matters for things like pointer arithmetic.  For example, assume the following code:

```
T a[N];
T *p = a;
T (*ap)[N] = &a;

printf( " p = %p,  p + 1 = %p\n", (void *) p, (void *) p + 1 );
printf( "ap = %p, ap + 1 = %p\n", (void *) ap, (void *) ap + 1 );
```

`p + 1` will yield the address of the next element of the array following `p`.  `ap + 1` will yield the address of the next *`N`-element array of `T`* following the current array.

There is no corresponding conversion rule for `struct` or other aggregate types, because there is no need to treat a `struct` expression as a pointer in some contexts vs. others.  The component selection operators `.` and `->` don't work the same way as the subscript operator.

---

<sup>1.  C was derived from an earlier programming language called B (go figure), and in B storage *was* set aside for a "pointer" to the first element of the array (in B, pointers were just integer offsets).  Ritchie kept B's array semantics when he started designing C, but ran into an issue when he started adding `struct` types; he didn't want to mix the array pointer metadata within the struct data.  He solved the problem by creating the conversion rule described above.</sup>